# API Endpoint URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter

Basically, the weather API; Apixu changed everything to weatherstack recently, including their endpoints and I need help updating my twitter weather bot.

I did go through the documentation, changed to axios but I keep getting the "Cannot Read Property error"

**My Old API Setup**

```
   const Twit = require('twit');
   const config = require('./config');
   const rp = require('request-promise-native');

async function setup(location) {
    const options = {
    url: "http://api.apixu.com/v1/current.json",
    qs: { 
          key: API_KEY,
          q: location
        },
    json: true
};
    let result = await rp(options);
    let condition = result.current.condition.text;
    let tweetText = `The condition in ${location} is currently ${condition}!`;
    console.log("TWEETING : ", tweetText);
    sendTweet(tweetText)
}
```

**According to their documentation, this is how it's supposed to be but I keep getting undefined errors.**

```
   const params = {
   access_key: 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY',
   query: 'New York'
}

axios.get('https://api.weatherstack.com/current', {params})
   .then(response => {
   const apiResponse = response.data;
   console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.location.name} is ${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`);
   }).catch(error => {
   console.log(error);
  });
```

The new Base URL: The new API requests start out with :

http://api.weatherstack.com/

documentation : https://weatherstack.com/quickstart

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'c
ondition' of undefined

UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection
 id: 1)

Comment: `result.current` is undefined. Check whether your `result` has data??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check the response.data.error object, if something goes wrong this will be populated. Funnily enough the http status code is still 200 for some error conditions.

```
axios.get('https://api.weatherstack.com/current', {params})
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.data.error) {
            const apiResponse = response.data;
            console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.location.name} is ${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Response error: code: ${response.data.error.code}, info: ${response.data.error.info}`)
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
    }
);
```

Using the free tier, I'm getting the following error with this request:

```
Response error: code: 105, info: Access Restricted - Your current Subscription Plan does not support HTTPS Encryption.
```

This is easily worked around by changing to http only (This will be less secure!):

```
axios.get('http://api.weatherstack.com/current', {params})
    .then(response => {
        if (!response.data.error) {
            const apiResponse = response.data;
            console.log(`Current temperature in ${apiResponse.location.name} is ${apiResponse.current.temperature}℃`);
        } else {
            console.log(`Response error: code: ${response.data.error.code}, info: ${response.data.error.info}`)
        }
    }).catch(error => {
        console.error("An error occurred: ", error);
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using free version you need to use 'http' to work, i guess if you want to use 'https' it is premiun that you need to buy
Here is the simple example that i have used
http://api.weatherstack.com/current?access_key=0a82bdc4c6628b5f968dd500d30a8857&query=19.0760,-72.8777

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).